# I have python 3.9 and i want to create virtual environment with python 3.7

Tags: python-3.7, python-3.9, kali-linux

Just installed kali 2021.1 and it has python 3.9. I need virtual environment of python 3.7 but its not being created. Tried to install 3.7 from deadsnakes repo with ppa but its saying no release file.
I want to create a virtual environment with python 3.7.
I used command "pipenv --python 3.7 " And it says like this Neither 'pyenv' nor 'asdf' could be found to install Python.
pip env is already installed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVaac.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
Use Pyenv to maintain different python versions

install pyenv from
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

then download required python version using pyenv
and create virtual environment using
pipenv --python "version"